# Why is terminal not parsing script for .bash_profile ? (goal is for this script to run and show the current working branch)

Tags: git

I hoping someone can answer this question, for I have checked many forums and have not come across any answers.

Setup:  Mac Big Sur
Application used : Terminal

Goal:  I am trying to get my active git directory to show the current branch that I am on.

Her is a screen shot of the issue and also the content of .bash_profile

- As you can tell I have tried multiple exports and for what I can tell they all follow the basic structure

Any help on this matter would be very appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Here is the screen shot with zprofile instead:
[image]

Comment: Can you post that command so that others can try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacOS Big Sur is in `zsh` and the equivalent is `~/.zprofile` 
You can use:

```
cd $HOME
ls -a
```

To view all your hidden files. If you look closely, there is no `.bash_profile`, but there is instead a `.zprofile`. Maybe this might help you :)

Comment: The OP is explicitly sourcing .bash_profile, so the name of the file isn't the specific issue here.  `zsh` might be the reason for this if it does not interpret the prompt string the same way ash bash.

Comment: Thanks zprofile makes sense.  I removed the .bash_profile that created and used prior.  Updated the zprofile instead.  Some result:

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about zsh.  Yes it seems that was a recent change with Big Sur, and to the looks of it that is how the terminal is ran in Big Sur.  The export being done / the interpretation of the string bring used is something that was normally interpreted by ash prior to.  I have not seen any zsh related versions of this script .

Answer (score 0):

It turns out yes it is a problem with zsh.  I was using ash version.  It needed a zsh version.  Thanks for the help.